# How to setup two different SAML apps for different set of users pointing to a single web App in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, idp

```
Fixed for all users - Web App URL - https//foo.bar.com

Entity ID - https//foo.bar.com/auth/callback?id=<unique-app-id>


Unique for each app
Callback URL - https//foo.bar.com/auth/callback?id=<unique-app-id>
```

Please suggest for Azure AD specific

Comment: Just redirect the authenticated users coming from these two apps in the browser to the new app. Single sign on will automatically sign in users in the new app without prompting for credentials.

Comment: Although why not just redirect the users trying to sign in to these tow apps to the new app?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by following approaches:

1. Configuring the application in different tenants in Azure AD.
2. Service provider can send ACS url to IDP, so that it can be redirected to that URL after login. Note: IDP initiated would use default ACS url in configuration in Azure AD.